# How to extract the audio streams and copy to another context in c?

Tags: c, ffmpeg, libav

I have a video file. It contains 1 video stream and 2 or more audio streams. I want to do some operation only on my audio streams. Is it possible to extract them and copy to another FormatContext structure?

```
AVFormatContext *afctx[no_of_audio_streams];
    for(i=0; i<no_of_audio_streams; i++){
            afctx[i] = avformat_alloc_context();
            afctx[i]->streams[0] = format_ctx->streams[i+1];
    }
```

But I am getting segmentation fault.

What is the proper way of copying, including the codec info and other relevant information?

Any suggestions or advice would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Whats the length of the `streams` array? Is it probably `no_of_audio_streams`? Because if so `streams[i+1]` causes your segmentation fault, because in the last run of your loop, you are trying to access memory that isn't there!

Comment: I don't think this is the answer you want, but Audacity is good for being able to record the audio when you play a video, but that may not be what you are looking for. If Audacity sorts you out it would be simpler than writing a new program....

Comment: @itzFlubby I already calculated the no.of audio streams available and moved the value to no_of_audio_streams.

Comment: @geo-freak Yes, that is clear, but what is the size of `streams` ? You must have defined its length somewhere by declaring it (`<datatype> streams[<size>]`)

Comment: @itzFlubby I didn't initialize the size and I never seen defining the size to a stream in libav.

Comment: Do you have debugging tools, which allow you to backtrace? With the help of those, you could find out. if the segfault occurs on calling`avformat_alloc_context()` or if it is just a buffer-overflow (this is what I suspect to be the case)!
Coming back to my previous comments, you can find out the size of the array with the function `sizeof()`. Could you please look up the size as well?